# How to performant connect a FTP Server to a Webdav Server?

Tags: performance, sockets, ftp, file-transfer, webdav

I have implemented a webdav directory in PHP using [Sabre DAV](https://code.google.com/p/sabredav/), for my website (Application Server Webinterface).

For this Website I am writing now an TCP Socket using C#, which is running on another server (actualy it is in the same datacenter, but for theoretical sake, it is on the other hemisphere).

The Socket actualy is a service, which can start and stop applications (gameserver in this case). I also have implemented a FTP Service in this socket too (for data transfer).

My Goal:

I want to connect my Web Dav to the FTP-Server of my socket, which means File Listening, Download, Upload. The usecase should be, that a user only connect to a single service. Imagine, my socket is running on more then one server.

If i would implement this with my current know how, i would do it this way:

- User Request Web Dav Directory
- Server make a file listening of the FTP Server
- The file listening is added dynamicly to the Web Dav Directory

Now the user open the directory, and want to download the file:

- Web Dav Server request the file from the Ftp server
- Web Dav Server provide the downloaded file
- Web Dav Server delete the provided file

On the other direction, the WebDav Server will accept a file, and upload it then to the FTP Server.

If the servers are not in the same datacenter, this cost traffic. Anyway, i think it takes some time, if the data are binrary instead of textbased configs. Also, the client side progress bar will not notice, if the *download to the webdav server* / *upload to the ftp server* is processed (the user possible think nothing happens).

I hope i have successful communicated, where my problem is.

So how can I implement this, without delegate an upload/download from one server to another? Is this even possible?

---

**Bonus**: Would a solution like *WebDav to Webdav* or *FTP to FTP* provide a better way of implementing it?

Comment: This probably wont help you, but if you could use java then you could use http://milton.io (java equivalent of sabredav) which comes with an embedded FTP server. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to achieve this is to have a third party software like webdrive to map the ftp server contents to a drive letter. Then point the webdav server to this drive. Windows also provides option to map a webdav/ftp URL as a drive letter so that the application can access it as if its a local drive.